# Generate frequency table from sql using Count with user defined condition

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

Basically I need to generate a frequency table using sql, and I have a sample table like this:

```
user_id   user_label     code1      date    
------   -----------    -----    ------  
1        x              a        01-01
1        x              a        01-01
1        x              a        01-02
1        x              b        01-01
1        x              c        01-02
1        y              a        01-01
2        x              a        01-01
```

etc

The rule to count occurrences is if two rows have the same user_id ,user_label and date ,then repeated codes should only be counted once.

For example, for the first two rows the frequency table should be :

```
user_id      user_label   code1   count_code_1
--------     -----------  -----   ------------
1            x            a       1
```

Because even though there are two instances of a, but they happen on the same date so should only be counted once and I need do this for every unique codes in code_1 column 
for all combinations of user_id + user_label

After processing the third row , the frequency table should be :

```
user_id      user_label   code_1   count_code_1
--------     -----------  ------   ------------
1            x            a        2
```

Since although is the same code ('a') but it happens on a different date (01-02) 
 
In the end, for the sample table given above, the desired result should be

```
user_id      user_label   code_1   count_code_1
--------     -----------  ------   -------------
1            x            a        2
1            x            b        1
1            x            c        1
1            y            a        1
2            x            a        1
```

What I have so far is

```
select t.user_id, t.user_label, t.code_1, count(###)
from t 
group by t.code_1,t.user_id, t.user_label
```

The problem is 
1. I don't know what to put inside the count 
 2. I don't know how to incorporate the condition on date in to this query.

Any suggestion, correction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `count(distinct date)`:

```
select t.user_id, t.user_label, t.code_1,
       count(distinct date)
from t 
group by t.code_1,t.user_id, t.user_label
```